# PHP namespace for multiple files

Tags: php, namespaces, include

I'm trying to include many files containing functions, classes and calls but I would like to put everything in a PHP namespace.
My issue is : all the files are part of another web application core. So I cannot edit the files.
Is there a way tu declare a namespace globally for a list of files ? 
Something like that :

```
namespace mynamespace {
    include_once("file1.inc.php");
    include_once("file2.inc.php");
    include_once("file3.inc.php");
    ...
}
```

Of course I tried this code and it does not work; all my tries failed while the first line of the include files where note namespace mynamespace;.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Every single file needs to declare its own namespace; you cannot force something to be in a different namespace using external code. <sub>(Some hacks like runkit or such will probably allow you to fiddle with that, but I'd consider this outside the regular scope of PHP as a language.)</sub>

Comment: Seems logic but I thought that if you can include a file, you could be able to set its namespace. Thanks a lot for your fast answer!

Comment: Think of namespaces as being part of the class's/function's name. Then maybe it's more obvious that you can't willy nilly rename things.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. A bit cumbersome (you need to list all classes) and works only if you have well behaved files that start with `<?php` and don't have a namespace in them. Also, because there's no decent error-reporting in eval'd stuff, use it only with well tested code.

```
<?php

namespace whatever;

use mynamespace\Class1FromFile1;
use mynamespace\Class2FromFile1;
use mynamespace\ClassFromFile2;
use mynamespace\ClassFromFile3;

function ns_inc ($lib, $ns) {
        eval("namespace $ns;" . substr(file_get_contents($lib), 5));
}

$ns= 'mynamespace';
ns_inc('file1.inc.php', $ns);
ns_inc('file2.inc.php', $ns);
ns_inc('file3.inc.php', $ns);
```